# Quartz scheduler not displaying Log4j messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to configure my Quartz scheduler to support logging. I had tried doing following:

Added log4j.xml in classes folder of my app. The code for the same is:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=
    %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
```

Added following statements in my scheduler class:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("QuartzReport.class");
logger.info("Info");
```

However, the console displays the following message with start up:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
    (org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Please tell me whether I am missing somthing.

Regards,
Ibu

Comment: Aprt from what Douglas mentioned, I guess you need to add category for org.quartz in log4j.properties

Answer (score 2):

You're missing essentialy two points:

1. Your configuration file is a properties file, not an XML. So you should save it as 'log4j.properties';
2. Make sure the file mentioned in the item 1 is in the application's classpath (assuming a recent log4j implementation is being used).

Good luck,

Douglas

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I took care of both points. please refer to my next answer segment for detailed comments.
Regards, Ibu

Answer (score 0):

Also try updating your log4j config with this line

log4j.logger.org.quartz=debug, stdout

Comment: Tried adding ur code in log4j.properties.Gotthefollowing error on deployment. However, the messages in the log file are printed as they were getting before. Plzrefermynextanswer.
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you code either programatically (as in the main method of your `QuartzReport` class), either with a configuration file (your properties file).

Newer versions of Log4j will try to load a file named `log4j.properties` from you classpath and use it to configure you logger automatically.

In your case, the `BasicConfigurator.configure()` call will override any definitions in you properties file (i.e., you properties file is being ignored). And the output displayed by the log respects the pattern you provided in the `PatternLayout` constructor. More details on how to define such pattern can be found in the [`PatternLayout` class documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).