# Is there a specific mechanism to Log within a job running in the Quartz scheduler API?

Tags: java, logging, quartz-scheduler

I am working on a system that runs a number of Quartz jobs.  Everything seems to be working fine but I am unclear on how Quartz wants me to log.

Does Quartz have some sort of logging mechanism itself, a preferred logging framework, or do I just use my plain old logging library as I would on any other project?

It seems that it would be nice to split out each job into its own log file or even append information about the job before each log message.

Comment: You can use log4j: http://stackoverflow.com/q/725228/130224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use any logging framework you want, e.g. [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) or [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j)
2. Quartz is just a Java library, it does not enforce any programming style or restrictions on your code, including specific logging API
3. There is a set of [Quartz plugins](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-plugins-hidden.html) that handle logging of each trigger/job start and end
4. If you want to separate logs from different jobs/job types, check out [MDC functionality in Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).